# Elm doesn't deduce type of Nothing value properly

Tags: type-inference, elm

I have a following piece of Elm code (getProjectView function is omitted for brievity):

```
type Model = Maybe List Project

model : Model
model = Nothing

getView : Model -> Html any
getView model =
  case model of
    Just projects ->
      ul [] (List.map getProjectView projects)

    Nothing -> p [] [ text "Still loading..." ]
```

When I try to compile the following snippet, the compiler fails with the following error:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH --------- E:\dev\irrelephant-code\client\elm\Views\Projects.elm

Tag `Maybe.Just` is causing problems in this pattern match.

32|     Just projects ->
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The pattern matches things of type:

    Maybe a

But the values it will actually be trying to match are:

    Model
```

Indicating that compiler can't deduce that this `Nothing` is a value of type `Model` (which in turn is an alias of type `Maybe List Project`).

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to explicitly mark this Nothing as a value of the Model type?

I am using elm v0.18.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to define model as a `type alias` of `Maybe (List Product)`.  Right now, with the `type` keyword, you are defining a new union/tag type with one value, `Maybe`, which expects to arguments, of type `List` and `Product`.

A working example is https://ellie-app.com/3MhPcgGzXqRa1/0

Comment: It is weird, you can redefine it like that.

Comment: `Nothing` itself is not a type, the type is `Maybe`

Comment: Yeah, you are right - I was initially trying to define the thing as an alias of ```Maybe List Product```, but it didn't work either. It seems that I've messed up with the brackets in this one, because ```Maybe List Product``` is different from ```Maybe (List Product)```